# Strange behaviour in KeyListener when using Clipboard

Tags: java, swing, jtable, clipboard, keylistener

I tried to do a simple <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> for my JTable, but when using the control button the whole row is copied, not the specified cell. How do I get the desired effect?

```
public class ClipboardTable {

private static final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
        .getSystemClipboard();
public static JTable tab;

public static void copyToClipboard(JTable ctaable) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < ctaable.getSelectedRows().length; i++) {
        str.append(ctaable.getValueAt(ctaable.getSelectedRows()[i], 0));
    }
    StringSelection strsel = new StringSelection(str.toString());
    clipboard.setContents(strsel, strsel);
    System.out.println("expected: "+str.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Object[][] data = {{1,2,3},{5,6,7},{8,9,0}};
    tab = new JTable(data, new String[] {"a","b","c"});
    KeyListener searchKeyListen = new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            ClipboardTable.copyToClipboard(ClipboardTable.tab); //this works fine
            if (e.isControlDown()) {
                if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C)) {
                    ClipboardTable.copyToClipboard(ClipboardTable.tab); // whole row is copied instead of only Cell
                }
            }
        }
    };
    tab.addKeyListener(searchKeyListen);
    jf.add(tab);
    jf.pack();
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: i just noticed CTRL+C is already implemented and thats whats interfeering

Comment: I though so too, but it seems by using `KeyBinding`s that behavior is passed (hence I deleted my comment) see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14126897/1133011).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Keybindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for Swing, as `KeyListener`/`KeyAdapter` has known issues when used with Swing components.

Seems to work fine with above implemented:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class ClipboardTable {

    private static final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getSystemClipboard();
    public static JTable tab;

    public static void copyToClipboard(JTable ctaable) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i < ctaable.getSelectedRows().length; i++) {
            str.append(ctaable.getValueAt(ctaable.getSelectedRows()[i], 0));
        }
        StringSelection strsel = new StringSelection(str.toString());
        clipboard.setContents(strsel, strsel);
        System.out.println("expected: " + str.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Object[][] data = {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 0}};
        tab = new JTable(data, new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});

        tab.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK, true), "CTRL C");
        tab.getActionMap().put("CTRL C", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                ClipboardTable.copyToClipboard(ClipboardTable.tab); // whole row is copied instead of only Cell
            }
        });

        jf.add(tab);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: i always hear that keyListener are worse, but i never see why. could you elaborate?

Comment: @schippi KeyListener is meant for AWT components, you are using Swing. Thus issues with focus may arise, i.e you expect the component to be focused by the KeyListener when in fact it does not (and thus you wont receive the KeyEvents etc.) this can be solved by calling `requestFocusInWinow()` on the component, but thats a hack. So mostly its because KeyAdapter is for AWT.

Comment: @schippi KeyListerner is a low level API which is generally unsuited for general interaction. You are not guaranteed of in what order KeyListeners will be called, meaning you could adversely effect other components who are waiting for the key stroke (or never be called because some other listener consumed it). KeyListener can only be notified if the component it is attached to has focus, KeyBindings can be configured to overcome many of these restrictions

Comment: +1 @MadProgrammer much better explanation, and that must have been why KeyListener and CTRL+C never worked for op as the Listener would intercept before the OS and thus OS would overwrite it

Answer (score 1):

You can set the selection range per cell:

```
tab.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

Note the preferred approach in Swing is to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListeners`

Comment: well, this is only an example - i want rowselection for overview, but only the values in the specified column should be copied, even when a cell from another column is selected

Answer (score 1):

You should

- Remove the `KeyListener`
- Opt for an `Action` with the correct [key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead. As `Action` you can use the `TransferHandler.getCopyAction()`
- Put a custom `TransferHandler` on your `JTable` in case you're not happy with the standard behavior